# Publishing both es6 and commonjs with subfolders

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, package.json, commonjs

- I want to be able to import module from subfolder like this, without any `lib` folder, https://davidwells.io/blog/publishing-flat-npm-packages-for-easier-import-paths-smaller-consumer-bundle-sizes/
- I want to publish both CommonJS and ES6 modules

I can specify the main file for commonjs with `"main": "./index.js"` and for es6 with `"module": "./index.es.js"` in `package.json`.

**But how does it works when I import `my-package/myfile` ? Is myfile.js used or myfile.es.js**

And why it isn't possible to specify a subfolder instead of a single main file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot of magic going on in that blog post you mentioned, he's just asking for `node_modules/his-module/P.js`

The bundlers need a single entry because (in theory) that is where you have your

```
module.exports = {}
```

code which is what lets the bundlers access your functions.

If you are using an esmodule compatible bundler like webpack or rollup, they will read the `module` key

```
import someFunction from 'your-module';
```

Would import the es module unless you are using something like browserify which would take the commonjs version.

You can also ask explicitly for a different file

```
import someFunction from 'your-module/lib/index.min.js';
```

Whatever file you ask for here, it'll import that. If you add a `/` after your-module you are now breaking out of the main or module path conventions and asking for whatever file you want.